# How does NewRelic's `Availability monitoring` monitor CDN's website?

Tags: monitoring, newrelic, high-availability

I have a domain that is hosted by a CDN(Akamai). This means depending on visitor's geographic region this domain will resolve into different IPs closest to the user.

NewRelic service can monitor a domain/website for availability from its "pinger" agents in multiple locations around the world.

How do those agents handle geo-distributed domains? Does each agent resolve the domain on its own? Or does some central agent resolves the domain and all other agents access the same IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each regional pinger performs its own lookup using a local resolver.